# Asked for sudo password only sometimes

Tags: permissions, sudo

This is more of a curiousity, trying to learn more about linux permissions. So I don't understand why I am able to sudo certain commands and not be prompted for a password but not others. I know that /usr/bin/sudo has a SUID bit which obviously makes sense. I am trying to escalate privelges to root and was wondering if I would be able use /usr/bin/sudo in any way. (This is on an authorized machine don't worry)

Here I show that I am in fact david

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ id
uid=1000(david) gid=1000(david) groups=1000(david),24(cdrom),25(floppy),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev)
```

Shows the SUID bit set for /usr/bin/sudo and the permissions on the two binaries in question

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ ls -la /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 157192 Oct 12 09:49 /usr/bin/sudo

david@traverxec:~/bin$ ls -la /usr/bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 138856 Feb 28  2019 /usr/bin/ls

david@traverxec:~/bin$ ls -la /usr/bin/journalctl 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67672 Aug 20  2019 /usr/bin/journalctl
```

Below Shows that this specific command using sudo to check logs of the webserver works perfectly **and doesn't prompt me for a password!**

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/journalctl -n5 -unostromo.service | /usr/bin/cat 
-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-03-02 12:00:21 EST, end at Mon 2020-03-02 12:11:05 EST. --
Mar 02 12:00:44 traverxec su[22169]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=33 euid=0 tty=pts/0 ruser=www-data rhost=  user=david
Mar 02 12:00:46 traverxec su[22169]: FAILED SU (to david) www-data on pts/0
Mar 02 12:07:26 traverxec nhttpd[23957]: /../../../../bin/sh sent a bad cgi header
Mar 02 12:07:38 traverxec nhttpd[24009]: /../../../../bin/sh sent a bad cgi header
```

When i try and run any other command using sudo **I am prompted for a password**

```
david@traverxec:~/bin$ /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ls /etc/shadow
[sudo] password for david:
```

**Why is this?**

Comment: `sudo` can be made to allow the execution of certain commands without having the give a password, either for all or for certain users or groups of users. This is done in the `sudoers` configuration file.

Comment: @Kusalananda Since I do not have read permissions on /etc/sudoers how else could I test to see what commands I have access to? Also I do not have the password for `david` since I am using SSH keys.

Comment: You may want to contact the administrator(s) of the system about that.

Comment: The output of `sudo -l` might help illustrate the commands/flags that were granted.

Comment: "sudo cat /etc/sudoers" should be illuminating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kusalananda♦ already mentioned, you configure sudo through the configuration file where you can archive the behavior you describe.

A user can invoke a specific command without the condition of giving a password. 
This does not mean you have full `sudo` access. You only have the permission to run a single command.

Sample configuration for that:

```
david ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/journalctl
```

(more at https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password)

- Even if you have a password for user "david" this does not automatically mean you can do anything more with `sudo`.
- There is no command for listing permissions which you got through sudo (without having access to `/etc/sudoers`). Its reasoned through how sudo works. Sudo just checks the configuration at the moment where you invoke a command with it - and this process needs superuser privileges. So there can't be an unprivileged tool which list the settings.

*Personal advice:
Try other methods for privilege escalations. Sudo is reasonable secure if the configuration is right.*

Comment: Thank you so much! Very clear explination. Yea going to try other methods, kinda figured sudo would be a dead end but I didn't like not understanding why it wasn't working. --cheers

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` will remember that you have entered a password, and not prompt again for a while (this depends on the configuration).

The `/etc/sudoers` file has the configuration for `sudo`.
You can set configure:

- which users
- which commands
- whether a password is needed.

It may be that it is set so that you can run some commands with no password.

All this has nothing to do with set-uid bit. This bit as you seem to know gives the program root privileges (see also capabilities: root is dead, long live capabilities). One `sudo` can do anything, it decides what to do based on its code, and the config file.